# Post particular values to particular div with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

How to make jquery to post values from a particular span to php, and then get values to a particular div? I'd like to have something like this: click span with class "more", that posts value from this li to php, and then via jquery to get value to div with id "test".

Here I have such a code which php gives me. I can add unique "id" for elements if it needs.

```
 <li>
    <span class="word">one word</span>
    <span class="numb">1</span>

    <span class="more">more</span>
    <div id="test"></div>
 </li>
 <li>
    <span class="word">another word</span>
    <span class="numb">13</span>

    <span class="more">more</span>
    <div id="test"></div>
 </li>
```

The problem is using this jquery I post only the first span containing class ".word" but instead of it I'd like to post only that spans where the span is. And get the values not to the first div with id "test" again but in the div where the span was clicked. My jquery-code is:

```
 $('.more').live("click",function() {

 var ID = $('.word').test();
 var DI = $('.numb').text();


      $.ajax({
           type:"POST",
           data: "value="+ ID + "&numb="+ DI,
           cache: false, 
           url: "more.php",
           success: function(msg){
                $('#test').html(msg).fadeIn('slow');
           }               
      });     
 });
```

By adding `var ID = $(this).attr("id");` instead of  `var ID = $('.word').test();` to jquery and to php `<span id="<?php echo $word; ?>" class="more">more</span>` I can post the unique value of word. But what about the other values? And the main problem is to post to the next div where the span-button "more" is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ID = $('.word').test();
```

replace it with

```
var ID = $('.word').text();
```

Also please use `.on` jQuery function instead of `.live` as `.live` is deprecated.

**Complete jQuery Code**

```
$(function()
{
    $('.more').on("click",function()
    {
        var clickedDiv = $(this);
        var ID = clickedDiv.parent().find('.word').text();
        var DI = clickedDiv.parent().find('.numb').text();

        $.ajax(
        {
            type:"POST",
            data: "value="+ ID + "&numb="+ DI,
            cache: false, 
            url: "more.php",
            success: function(msg)
            {
                clickedDiv.find('div[custom_id="test"]').html(msg).fadeIn('slow');
            }               
        });     
    });
});
```

One more thing do not repeat same `ID` for `DOM`.

**ID MUST BE UNIQUE.**

For that i used `<div custom_id = "test"></div>`

**Updated HTML**

```
<li>
    <span class="word">one word</span>
    <span class="numb">1</span>

    <span class="more">more</span>
    <div custom_id = "test"></div>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="word">another word</span>
    <span class="numb">13</span>

    <span class="more">more</span>
    <div custom_id = "test"></div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you for you help but I have some issues. The first thing posting unique values for spans is working. The second one it seems that                 `clickedDiv.find('div[custom_id="test"]').html(msg).fadeIn('slow');` doesn't work for me. I have the same div as you:    ` <div  custom_id="test"></div>` and I've even tries to add to that div unique id but it makes nothing

Comment: @zmogusnamas please see updated answer i have added html please make sure html is same as in answer...

Comment: yes everything is the same. When I try to have     `$('.more').on("click",function()` it doesn't' work at all. My Jquery's version is 1.7.1. Maybe is it possible to have a kind of next() there? /// I've tried to have                 `clickedDiv.next().html(msg).fadeIn('slow');` it works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this can work out even without the ajax request if you are not doing any thing on the php side .
Check this code :

in the html make the div with class instead of id .

```
<li>
    <span class="word">one word</span>
    <span class="numb">1</span>

    <span class="more">more</span>
    <div class="test"></div>
 </li>
 <li>
    <span class="word">another word</span>
    <span class="numb">13</span>

    <span class="more">more</span>
    <div class="test"></div>
 </li>
```

then

```
$('.more').click(function (){

 var ID = $('.word').text();
 var DI = $('.numb').text();

 var Data = "value="+ ID + "&numb="+ DI;

 $(this).closest('.test').html(Data); // use anyone of them
 or 
 $(this).sibling('.test').html(Data); // use anyone of them

});
```

this will work perfectly . This is the updated code

Comment: check out the above code i have edited it . changed the div with class instead of id .

Comment: The problem is I have to post values to php-code which does something with those values and then I get the modified values via            `success: function(msg)`. And unfortunately your solution doesn't suit me :